# MAC OS Maven: Not recognizing exported environment variables

Tags: bash, macos, shell, maven, environment-variables

I want to build a maven project using a shell script. Consider the scenario

In my project, i have some test such as

```
public class MyTest{

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
   String libPath = System.getenv("LIBRARY_PATH");
    if (libPath == null || libPath.isEmpty()) {
      logger.error(
          "LIBRARY_PATH not found. Please set this env variable to denote the location of the binaries that need to be loaded");
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "LIBRARY_PATH not found. Please set this env variable to denote the location of the binaries that need to be loaded");
    }
    logger.info("LIBRARY_PATH found. All the binaries will be loaded from here {}", libPath);
}
/*Some tests that depend on LIBRARY_PATH being set*/
}
```

now, i have a shell script `build_project` that does the following

```
#!/bin/bash -e

if [ -z $1 ] ; then
    echo "Must provide LIBRARY_PATH"
    exit 1
fi

source setup_work.sh $1

mvn clean install
```

and here is the `setup_work.sh` script

```
#!/bin/bash -e

export LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/$1
echo "LIBRARY_PATH is ${LIBRARY_PATH}"
# some other setup tasks specific to my project
```

finally, all i do is run

`build_project.sh /some/path/`

and it works totally fine on linux/ubuntu

however, it does not work on MAC OS. I see

```
LIBRARY_PATH is workingDir/some/path/
/*
lots of maven messages
.
.
.
*/
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running my.project.package.MyTest
[ERROR] LIBRARY_PATH not found. Please set this env variable to denote the location of the binaries that need to be loaded
IllegalArgumentException
```

Does the problem lie with maven or MAC OS? Why am i not able to export the env variable form the shell script?

Finally, note that if i add the following in my `bash_profile`

`export LIBRARY_PATH=some/path/i/need`

then it works on MAC OS. This leads me to believe that the problem lies with MAC OS.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does your path appear in the output of `env` if you run that after the `source` but before `mvn`?

Comment: yes, thats the weird part. i have the echo statement before i call maven and i can clearly see on the console that the env variable is set

Comment: `echo` just outputs the value of the shell variable, whether or not it was actually exported. Running `env` after `source` returns will help verify that the variable is truly exported, in which case there is a problem with `mvn`.

Comment: oh ok, let me try

Comment: i can confirm that the env variable is set. i added `env | grep LIBRARY_PATH` and i saw the value on the console